# dense_rank filling up tempdb on SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got this query here which uses dense_rank to number groups in order to select the first group only. It is working but its slow and tempdb (SQL server) becomes so big that the disk is filled up. Is it normal for dense_rank that it's such a heavy operation? And how else should this be done then without resorting to coding?

```
select
a,b,c,d
from
    (select a,b,c,d,
    dense_rank() over (order by s.[time] desc) as gn
    from [Order] o
     JOIN Scan s ON s.OrderId = o.OrderId
     JOIN PriceDetail p ON p.ScanId = s.ScanId) as p
where p.OrderNumber = @OrderNumber
and p.Number = @Number
and p.Time > getdate() - 20
and p.gn = 1
group by a,b,c,d,p.gn
```

Comment: because it would be coding. He look for a magical silver bullet without changing a single letter in the SQL - which would be coding and such an answer is not wanted.

Comment: I meant not resorting to C# coding, it should be possible with plain sql to select only the first group of data and dense_rank seems to do exactly that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any operation that has to sort a large dataset may fill tempdb. dense_rank is no exception, just like rank, row_number, ntile etc etc.

You are asking for a sort over what appears to be a global, complete sort of every scan entry, since database start. The way you expressed the query the join must occur before the sort, so the sort will be both big and wide. After all is said and done, consuming a lot of IO, CPU and tempdb space, you will restrict the result to a small subset for only a specified order and some conditions (which mentions columns not present in projection, so they must be some made up example not the real code).

- You have a filter on `WHERE gn=1` followed by a `GROUP BY gn`. This is unnecessary, the gn is already unique from the predicate so it cannot contribute to the group by.
- You compute the dense_rank over every order scan and then you filter by `p.OrderNumber = @OrderNumber AND p.gn = 1`. This makes even less sense. This query will only return results if the @OrderNumber happens to contain the scan with rank 1 over all orders! It cannot possibly be correct.

Your query makes no sense. The fact that is slow is just a bonus. Post your actual requirements.

If you want to learn about performance investigation, read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

PS. As a rule, computing ranks and selecting =1 can always be expressed as a TOP(1) correlated subquery, with usually much better results. Indexes help, obviously.

PPS. Use of group by without any aggregate function is yest another serious code smell.